# Copy / paste JetBrains PyCharm behavior

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm new to PyCharm and cannot understand it's **copy/paste** behavior - 
If i copy `code('foobar')` and insert it **inside** code i've got

```
code-code-codefoobarcode-code
```

and it's right as for me, but if i paste **'foobar'** at the end of line i've got

```
foobar code-code-code-code
```

e.g. it appears at begining of line. Is it a bug or a feature?) Can I change editor's behaviour?

I'm using PyCharm 145.597.11

Comment: Can you insert this code here? I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: Suppose this question is related to code formatting in PyCharm as Python has formatting aware syntax?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior I was confused of difference between "paste simple" and "paste".
I've found keymap editor and edited shortcuts. Thanks.